# I want to input elements of a variable-length array in a single line in C

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

so I want to run a for loop with scanf() to read the elements of an array in one line. But the problem is that scanf() keeps going to the next line. I want to get around this. Also, I cannot just write scanf("%d%d%d...%d", &x1, ..., &xn) because the length of array is variable and must also be input from the user.

I tried searching on the internet, but to no avail. I briefly considered the y[i]=getchar() function, only to immediately realize that getchar() is the epitome of new line commands.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &array[i])` in a loop should work. It won't go to the next line.

Comment: Read a full line with `fgets` and parse with `sscanf`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja That's hard to do with a variable number of items, since each call to `sscanf()` will start from the beginning of the string.

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: ... you could use %n to figure out how much you read.  If you have a max elements read all n at a time and figure out from the return value how many you got.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of "How to use `sscanf()` in a loop?" as that allows you to process the elements of a single line read by `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`.

Comment: @Barmar Not so hard, just need to keep moving along the string. https://godbolt.org/z/dGxMevE19

Comment: @RetiredNinja `%n` is a relatively advanced `sscanf` feature.

Comment: @Barmar Can't keep the training wheels on forever.